# Why isn't the whole folder served on the root when using UseFileServer in OWIN?

Tags: asp.net, owin

I'm building a simple demo app where I want to use the `StaticFile` extensions. To configure it I have the following code:

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
{
        FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\content"),
        RequestPath = PathString.Empty,
        EnableDefaultFiles = true
});
```

In the folder `content` I have an `index.html` which is server directly when I visit `/` as expected, but files are not served as expected.

```
content
    index.html
    app
        lib
            something.js
```

This is the file structure I have and what I want is to access `something.js` at the url `/app/lib/something.js` but with the code I have now I have to use `/content/app/lib/something.js` which I don't want. Why does the `index.html` get served directly when I visit `/` but not when I go to `/index.html` and the same goes for the js file.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get those results?